# Google guava ImmutableList equals Method returns a different result than java.utils.List, breaking List-Interface contract?

Tags: java, guava

I just stumbled across problem, and i'm not quite sure if I'm missing something, or something is broken.

I'm using google guava(19.0). And something fishy happened when i tested ImmutableLists for equality.

In the Javadoc to ImmutableList it says that ImmutableList implements the java.util.List interface
http://docs.guava-libraries.googlecode.com/git/javadoc/com/google/common/collect/ImmutableList.html

Because of this, i would assume that the equals method of ImmutableList, would follow the contract, given by java.util.List, and return the same result for the same Lists

In List.equals() it says
"[...]In other words, two lists are defined to be equal if they contain the same elements in the same order. This definition ensures that the equals method works properly across different implementations of the List interface."

https://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/List.html#equals(java.lang.Object)

Now think about this small code sample

```
    ImmutableList.Builder<String> builder1 = new ImmutableList.Builder<>();
    builder1.add("Test1");
    List<String> list1 = builder1.build();


    ImmutableList.Builder<String> builder2 = new ImmutableList.Builder<>();
    builder1.add("Test1");
    List<String> list2 = builder2.build();

    System.out.println(list1.equals(list2));
    //--> false


    List<String> defaultList1 = new LinkedList<>();
    defaultList1.add("Test1");

    List<String> defaultList2 = new LinkedList<>();
    defaultList2.add("Test1");

    System.out.println(defaultList1.equals(defaultList2));
    // --> true
```

Now, what output would you expect?

I expected it to be *true* for both tests.
But the actual output is different. The java version of equals returns true, as expected. But the guava version returns false.

If you now have a look at the javadoc for google immutableList, it says that the equals method returns o1==o2 (which is in violation of the List-Interface contract). So i understand WHY my code sample works the way it works.

I assume that this is not a "bug" by the google guys, but a problem with my understanding of Iterfaces and contracts

Comment: Look very carefully at these two lines `ImmutableList.Builder<String> builder2 = new ImmutableList.Builder<>();
    builder1.add("Test1");`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you are adding the element to the same builder ( in your case builder1). see below. so builder2 actually doesn't have anything and hance equals return false.

```
ImmutableList.Builder<String> builder1 = new ImmutableList.Builder<>();
builder1.add("Test1"); // builder1
List<String> list1 = builder1.build();


ImmutableList.Builder<String> builder2 = new ImmutableList.Builder<>();
builder1.add("Test1"); // again builder1
List<String> list2 = builder2.build();

System.out.println(list1.equals(list2));
//--> false


List<String> defaultList1 = new LinkedList<>();
defaultList1.add("Test1");

List<String> defaultList2 = new LinkedList<>();
defaultList2.add("Test1");

System.out.println(defaultList1.equals(defaultList2));
// --> true
```